# Meteor: When the client insert a document, how does the server and client generates the same _id?

Tags: meteor

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';


export const play = new Mongo.Collection('play');

Meteor.methods({
    'play.insert':(value)=>{
        let doc_id = play.insert({value});
        console.log(doc_id);
    }
});
```

When this method is called, both client side and server side have the same doc_id.
How does this possible? How does the server know what _id the client is used?
Because when play.insert({value}) is invoked in the server, {value} have no _id, how does the server "knows" which id to use?

Comment: As far as I know, it will sync the same record on the client to the server. We don't need to handle the _id as the generated id will be almost unique and the change to have a conflict with the records that are in the server is almost impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official Meteor guide

> Each Meteor Method invocation shares a random generator seed with the client that called the Method, so any IDs generated by the client and server Methods are guaranteed to be the same. This means you can safely use the IDs generated on the client to do things while the Method is being sent to the server, and be confident that the IDs will be the same when the Method finishes. One case where this is particularly useful is if you want to create a new document in the database, then immediately redirect to a URL that contains that new document’s ID.

If you would like to learn more about it, you can check [this](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#consistent-id-generation) section of Meteor guide.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I  needed. Thank you!